# Como instalar o TortoiseSVN no Deepin?

Tags: linux, instalador

Existe alguma forma de usar o TortoiseSVN no Deepin?

Comment: "*TortoiseSVN is an Apache™ Subversion (SVN)® client, implemented as a Windows shell extension.*". O Tortoise, particularmente, não será possível. Se for possível alternativas, acredito que você deve deixar explícito a pergunta.

Comment: Vi que algumas das suas perguntas foram fechadas recentemente, recomendo dar uma olhada no guia [ask] para aumentar as suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Há como instalar um software parecido com o TortoiseSVN.

- [Rabbit VCS](https://simasware.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/rabbit-cvs-o-tortoise-svn-para-linux/)

O comando para instalar o Rabbit é  esse:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3 rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-cli
```

Para mais detalhes, confira o link informado.

Comment: cara é o seguinte eu uso atualmente o deepin

Comment: e o deepin não aceita repositório

Comment: Bom, você não informou isso na pergunta, não tinha como adivinhar.